# Getting JavaScript table element from span element

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the table in for format:

```html
<table class="list" id='obid'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Id</th>
           <th>name</th>
           <th>address</th> 
           <th>city</th> 
           <th>country</th> 
           <th>province</th> 
           <th>postalcode</th> 
           <th>primaryphone</th> 
           <th>secondaryphone</th> 
           <th>website</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

When the table is clicked I can receive the whole of the data from each row which works fine. However it pulls the span HTML text as well.

```html
"span style="cursor:pointer;">2</span"
```

How would I go about just puling the value "2"? Currently I have this:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
tbody.onclick = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var data = [];
    var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
    if (target) {
        var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
    console.log(data[0]);  
};
```

MY html is created as so:

```
$res=array();
if($result)
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while(($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false)
        {
        
            
            $r=array();
            
    
            
            
            
            $r[]="<span style='cursor:pointer;'  >".$data['id']."</span>";
            $r[]="<span style='cursor:pointer;'  >".$data['name']."</span>";
            $r[]="<span style='cursor:pointer;'  >".$data['address']."</span>";
            $r[]="<span style='cursor:pointer;'  >".$data['city']."</span>";
            $r[]="<span style='cursor:pointer;'  >".$data['country']."</span>";
            $r[]="<span style='cursor:pointer;'  >".$data['province']."</span>";
            $r[]="<span style='cursor:pointer;'  >".$data['postalcode']."</span>";
            $r[]="<span style='cursor:pointer;'  >".$data['primaryphone']."</span>";
            $r[]="<span style='cursor:pointer;'  >".$data['secondaryphone']."</span>";
            $r[]="<span style='cursor:pointer;'  >".$data['website']."</span>";
            
            $res[]=$r;
            
            
        }
        
    }


echo json_encode($res);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try change this

```js
data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
```

to this (it selects the first Child of the cell element, that is the span)

```js
data.push(cells[i].firstChild.innerHTML);
```

or simply

```js
data.push(cells[i].innerText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`. You want just a text value, not HTML around...

```
console.log(data[0].innerText);
```